# Time complexity of recursive code in 2D matrix (find the largest square containing only 1's)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm having an m x n binary matrix filled with 0's and 1's, and I'm finding the largest square containing only 1's.

I have written the recursive code for it(max stores the size of largest square containing only 1's) and it works fine but i want to know the time complexity of this code

```
int max = 0;    
int solveRec(char[][] mat, int i, int j){
    if(i>=mat.length || j>=mat[0].length)
        return 0;
    
    int right = solveRec(mat, i, j+1);
    int diagnol = solveRec(mat, i+1, j+1);
    int down = solveRec(mat, i+1, j);
    
    if(mat[i][j]=='1'){
        int ans = 1+Math.min(right, Math.min(diagnol, down));
        max = Math.max(max, ans);
        return ans;
    } else
        return 0;
}
```

I know to find the Time complexity of 1D array recursive calls where array size decreases but here there are 3 recursive calls

Comment: I think it’s O(N^3) where min(I, J) = N and I, J are the initial values that you pass to the function. However you need to trace by using a reasonably sized matrix.

Comment: I believe the code won't terminate if the board contains at least 2 connected ones.
It will do 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> ... recursively.
You need to keep a visited set of the visited squares or override squares from 1 to 0.

Comment: @IsmailMaj The termination condition is on i & j and I'm incrementing either i or j or both in every recursive call so there will be a time when i>=mat.length or  j>=mat[0].length at this point it will terminate